# Making a profiler in c++ get Incorrect output from method

Tags: c++

I have been working on a profiler project for a few weeks now. I have the project mostly complete except for one output error coming from one of my methods.

I believe it might have something to do with where the if(it == child.end()) statement is placed. I tried moving it around but I still can't get the result I'm looking for.

```
// Adds in the report to the main.
// Assumes only one return at end of main body.

void AST::mainReport(std::vector<std::string>& profileName) {

std::list<AST*>::iterator it = child.begin();

while (it != child.end()) {
    if ((*it)->tag == "function") {
        AST *newPtr = (*it)->getChild("block");
        std::list<AST*>::iterator itr = newPtr->child.begin();

        if (it == child.end()) {
            while ((*itr)->tag != "return") {
                ++itr;
            }
        }
        --itr;

        AST *output = new AST(token);
        std::string out;
        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = profileName.begin(); i != profileName.end(); ++i) {
            out = out + ("std::cout<< " + *i + " <<std::endl; \n");
        }
        output->text = out;
        newPtr->child.insert(itr, output);
    }
    ++it;
}
}
```

This method is supposed to insert 2 `cout` statement right before the return as shown in the main function:

```
int main() {  
          int i;
          i = 0;          
          while (i < 10) {    
            ++i;
            std::cout << i;
          }
          std::cout << foo_cpp << std::endl;    // Here
          std::cout << main_cpp << std::endl;   // Here
          return 0;
        }
```

Instead, my method is inserting the `cout` statements after main has left its scope, causing errors:

```
int main() {  
          int i;
          i = 0;          
          while (i < 10) {    
            ++i;
            std::cout << i;
          }
          return 0;
        } std::cout << foo_cpp << std::endl;    // Here
          std::cout << main_cpp << std::endl;   // Here
```

I'm sorry if the code is messy or vague, I've been getting frustrated trying to figure it out. I can give more background and information if needed. Thanks for looking.

Comment: It'd be good for you to include the errors at least. Also, see if you can reproduce the error in a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that here instead.

Comment: Because of the loop condition (`while (it != child.end())`) the condition you attempt  inside the loop (`if (it == child.end())`) will *never* be true. If you haven't done much debugging before, now is definitely the time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: By the way, the (outer) loop you have is equal to `for (auto it = child.begin(); it != child.end(); ++it)`. I really recommend using the `for` loop instead.

Comment: Consider using some `enum` instead of `"function"` or `"block"`